# Помогите решить 24 задание из егэ

Tags: python

Текстовый файл 24-s1[введите сюда описание ссылки](https://kpolyakov.spb.ru/cms/files/ege-sym/24-s1.txt).txt состоит не более чем из 106 заглавных латинских букв (A..Z). Текст разбит на строки различной длины. Определите количество строк, в которых буква J встречается чаще, чем буква E.

Answer (score 4):

```
res = 0
with open("file.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
        res += line.count("J") > line.count("E")
print(res)
```